# AngularMaterial Autocomplete Loading Animation does not stop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, autocomplete, angular-material

### Background:

I am learning AngularJS and using AngularMaterial.

To test it, I decided to create an example out of the code given in the [documentation (check codepen)](https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/demo/autocomplete). My application is a nodeJS application in Cloud9 and is very simple.

### Code:

It is divided into 3 main files, `index.html` (which contains the autocomplete box), `server.js` (containing server logic), and `autocomplete.js` (client side logic).

Following are the `index.html` file and then the `autocomplete.js` files. Because I have my server running in Cloud9, and this example is linked to it, you can check the small example running live !

```js
/*global angular*/

'use strict';
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache']).controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);

function DemoCtrl($q, $log, $http) {
    
    this.searchText = null;
    
    this.querySearch =function(query) {
        let serverUrl = '//material-complete-fl4m3ph03n1x.c9users.io/getStates';
        let deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: serverUrl,
            params: {
                word: query
            }
            
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            $log.error(response);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    this.searchTextChange = function(text) {
        $log.info('Text changed to ' + text);
    };

    this.selectedItemChange = function(item) {
        $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
    };
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-cloak>

    <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" class="autocompletedemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
            <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">

                <md-autocomplete md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)" md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)" md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)" md-item-text="item.display" md-min-length="0"
                placeholder="What is your favorite US state?">
                    <md-item-template>
                        <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
                    </md-item-template>
                    <md-not-found>
                        No states matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found.
                    </md-not-found>
                </md-autocomplete>
                <br>

            </form>
        </md-content>
    </div>

    <!--CSS files-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc4/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.0-rc4/docs.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">

    <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc4/angular-material.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Your application bootstrap  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/autocomplete.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Additionally, here is the code of my `server.js` file, which uses NodeJs and ExpressJs:

```
//Lets define a port we want to listen to
const PORT = 8080;

//Init Vars
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//Init Functions
//we allow CORS: http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log('Example app listening on port ' + PORT + '!');
});

//GET methods
app.get('/getStates', function(req, res, next) {

  var createFilterFor = function(query) {
    var lowercaseQuery = query.toLowerCase();

    return function filterFn(state) {
      return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) > -1);
    };

  };

  //get parameters from GET: https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters
  var query = req.param('word');

  var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
              Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
              Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
              Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
              North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
              South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
              Wisconsin, Wyoming';

  var statesMap = allStates.split(/, +/g).map(
    function(state) {
      return {
        value: state.toLowerCase(),
        display: state
      };
    });

  var result = query ? statesMap.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : statesMap;
  res.send(result);
});
```

### What works:

Now, if you play around you can select an American state within a list. The list filters according to what you type and allows you to select something. If you use developer tools you can also see the logs in the console, further demonstrating that the query is working and so is the selection.

### What does not:

The problem here, is when you clear the text box. If you pick a state, and then clear it (by pressing the cross or pressing Escape), you will see a blue bar bellow the input box:

[image: blue_bar_under_box]

This indicates that a query is being done. The problem is that I don't see any request being sent to the server, and the I get stuck in an infinite query! Even when apparently I am not doing it!

What am I missing here? Can someone help me?

### Extra

For those interested, here is the GitHub repo of the example!

- https://github.com/Fl4m3Ph03n1x/material-complete

All help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning the promise from the wrong location and not returning the chain properly, so it doesn't resolve properly.

Try this (note the return in front of the call to $http):

```
this.querySearch =function(query) {
    let serverUrl = '//material-complete-fl4m3ph03n1x.c9users.io/getStates';
    let deferred = $q.defer();
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: serverUrl,
        params: {
            word: query
        }

    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        if(response.data.length>0) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data); }
        else {
            var nada=[]
            deferred.resolve(nada); }
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        $log.error(response);
        deferred.reject(response);
        return deferred.promise;
    });


};
```

TLDR version from the comments. This is a known bug and the fix isn't released as of this writing. The workaround is either to rollback to AM 1.06 or use css to hide the progressbar. CSS:

```
md-autocomplete md-progress-linear { display: none; }
```

Comment: I tested with you code and after selecting something and clearing, I still get the same problem :S

Comment: I think you are also missing another return. I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Still not working, you can check the example here: https://preview.c9users.io/fl4m3ph03n1x/material-complete/client/index.html?_c9_id=livepreview0&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io
 kudos++ for trying though ...

Comment: I think you might be getting an error inside the AM materials. Try adding if (! query) { return} at the top of your function and see if you can just prevent the autocomplete from kicking in at that point.

Comment: Maybe I am seeing something wrong here, but the function must return a value. I tried what you suggested (along with other variations where I try to prevent the server call) and the result is always the same: it blows up!

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the key. Try the edits above. I'm not sure if that's what you want. I think you want all the states like if you back space the result out. When you hit the closebox or escape, the query value must be different. You might just be able to do if (!query) {query=''} at the top of your function to force an empty string if that's the case.

Comment: Also tried that, but nothing seems to work ... I honestly don't know what could be causing it ...

Comment: I tried comparing what you're doing to a couple of md-autocompletes in my app and I don't see any real differences and I'm not seeing this behavior with mine. The only other differences I see that's not app related is that I have md-no-cache="true" and md-min-length="3"

Comment: If you allow cache, and set the input-min to 0, it is  likely that you will see this same behavior.

Comment: Probably, but I can't pull down 10,000 records to find out. :)

Comment: So, turns out that this is a known bug: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/8301 I am not sure if the changes have been released yet. It was closed 10 days ago. The code changes related to promises I recommended above should still be useful for you though. :)

Comment: Damn shame.... The thing is that if I add `md-min-length=3` (or greater than zero for that matter), I wont have this problem. However, right now, I need it to be = 0.

Comment: A bug ? I thoght as much ... well, it **will not be fixed**. Angular Material is officially deprecated and discontinued, no one will fix this. They are instead working in Angular Material 2.0 (for AngularJS 2.0). If you can add that to your asnwer, I will accept it and reward you with the bounty.

Comment: I don't think that's true. They just added a few new features and state on their home page that they are "focused on bug fixes and minor improvements." There are commits in the last week. You are using a release candidate version. You might be able to go back to 1.06 and avoid it. Also, since your query is pretty much instant and cached, you could use the work around mentioned in the bug report, just a little css.: md-autocomplete md-progress-linear { display: none; }

Comment: Ok, I will give it a shot ! I thought it was discontinued after this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ngmaterial/4ActiQp3nA0

Comment: I rolled back to 1.0.6. It worked ! You have rightfully earned yourself the bounty ! Wish you good luck, and I hope we see each more times! I am sure I will need your help again in the future :p

Answer (score 1):

Set `md-min-length` to `1` - you don't really want to be suggesting completions until from an external service until a user has started typing.

```
<md-autocomplete 
  md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)" 
  md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)" 
  md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)" 
  md-item-text="item.display"
  md-min-length="1"
  placeholder="What is your favorite US state?">
  <md-item-template>
    <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
  </md-item-template>
  <md-not-found>
    No states matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found.
  </md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Comment: If I do it that way, when the user clicks on the box, nothing happens. I would like to show all the states when the user first clicks on the box, so having `min-length="0"` is something I need. If I didn't need that, your answer would have been accepted though. Kudos++ for trying.